# I'm stuck finding the maclaurin series for $f(x) = \ln(1+5x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I've calculated the first $4$ derivatives of $f(x)$ and evaluated each at $x=0$. I now have the following maclaurin series:

$$ 0 + 5x - \frac{25}{2!}x^2 + \frac{250}{3!}x^3 - \frac{3750}{4!}x^4 $$

I am awful at recognizing patterns, and need to come up with a series for this from $n=1$ to infinity. Additionally, if anyone has any tips for recognizing patterns like this, let me know, because it's something I need to be better at.

Comment: Well, 

$1/(1+x)$ is $1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-x^5+....$

You can see the pattern there, right?

When you integrate it, the left hand side is $\ln(1+x)$. Can you see the pattern in the right hand side?

Now substitute $5x$ in place of $x$. What's the pattern now?

Answer (score 1):

If you know that
$\ln(1+x)
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}x^k}{k}
$,
just substitute
$5x$ for $x$
to get
$\ln(1+5x)
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}(5x)^k}{k}
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^k\dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}5^k}{k}
$.

Answer (score 0):

$$5=5^1*0!$$
$$25=5^2*1!$$
$$250=5^3*2!$$
$$3750=5^4*3!$$

Perhaps this may help

$$f(x)=-\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(-5)^{i}}{i}x^i$$

Answer (score 0):

When looking for the general term of a Taylor series, it's best to not evaluate the products. E.g.,

$$
\begin{alignat*}{}
f(0) &&= \phantom{-}0 \\
f'(0) &= \phantom{-}\frac{5}{\phantom{(}1 + 5x\phantom{)^1}}\biggr|_{x=0} &= \phantom{-}5 \\
f''(0) &= -\frac{5^2}{(1 + 5x)^2}\biggr|_{x=0} &= -5^2 \\
f^{(3)}(0) &= \phantom{-}\frac{2 \cdot 5^3}{(1 + 5x)^3}\biggr|_{x=0} &= \phantom{-}2 \cdot 5^3 \\
f^{(4)}(0) &= -\frac{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5^4}{(1 + 5x)^4}\biggr|_{x=0} &= -3 \cdot 2 \cdot 5^4
\end{alignat*}
$$

The general term should be apparent after this: $f^{(n)}(0) = (-5)^{n-1} (n-1)!$ for $n \geq 1$.

Comment: So $f^{(n)}(0)/n! = ...$.